# Can a section of a text be set with only even/odd page numbers

Tags: page-numbering

Is is possible to set a run of pages as only even, or only odd, so that all of the page style elements of even or odd pages (margins, headers, footers, etc.) are associated with them and they are numbered n*2, n*2+1, etc?

I'm currently using the memoir class, but this is not absolutely necessary.

(I know that there are various packages for flowing text in columns, or pages, but can't use these for various reasons.)

Comment: answer is yes in any case but could you clarify your question. do you want the printed page numbers to be 1,2,3, but all using the odd page (or even page) layout, or do you want the printed page numbers to be 1,3,5,7, what do you want `\cleardoublepage` to do?

Comment: I know about \cleardoublepage, but this is not what I want. I need the pages to run text continuously with no blank pages, no pagebreaks, etc., but the page numbers should be 2, 4, 6, ... (or 1, 3, 5, ...), and the pages should have all the elements of these pages - that is, the headers should give the information for even or odd pages only, and the margins should be set up for even or odd pages only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This adjusts the page count to go up in 2, so as it starts at 1, you get pages 1,3,5,7 all with an odd page style

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\old@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{\old@outputpage\stepcounter{page}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\newcount\z
\section{aaa}
aaa
\subsection{bbb}

{\loop\ifnum\z<1000 \romannumeral\z\ \advance\z1 \repeat}

\section{aaa aaa}
aaa
\subsection{bbb bbb}

{\loop\ifnum\z<1000 \romannumeral\z\ \advance\z1 \repeat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! That does the job nicely.